# Codeigniter ->from(multiple tables)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello stackoverflow people :) 
I want to get data from, let's say, 2 tables. I dont want any specific 'where' option, so that's my model code:

```
$this->db->from('table1, table2');      
$this->db->order_by('table1.date, table2.date', "desc");
$query = $this->db->get('', $num, $offset);

return $query->result_array();
```

This way i get only information from 'table2', which contains only 1 article, and this article echoing several times on page. These two tables have the same structure and i hoped that writing 'order_by' this way would help, but no. If i do any other manipulation i get information only from one table. Order by date is important to keep. 
Hopefully anyone would find this question interesting and would help aswell. Thanks in advance!

**Edited part:**
Function:

```
$this->db->get("table1");

$comm_numbers = $this->db->count_all_results("table1");

$config['base_url'] = base_url();
$config['total_rows'] = $comm_numbers;
$config['per_page'] = '5';
$config['uri_segment'] = 1;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$this->load->model("model_get_all");
$data["results"] = $this->model_get_all->getData1($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(1));
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: Tell us the columns of Table1 and Table2

Comment: I think you would want to use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) instead of a join if the table structure is the same on both tables

Comment: id, title, text, views, date, image. I already worked with these tables and i retrieved information from them, if i work separatly with each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT id, title, text, views, date, image FROM table1 UNION SELECT id, title, text, views, date, image FROM tablee2');
```

**Update:**
Query with CodeIgniter Pagination:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT id, title, text, views, date, image FROM table1 UNION SELECT id, title, text, views, date, image FROM tablee2 LIMIT $offset, $num");
```

**Update 2:** Ok, I change only the place when `$offset` goes `null`.

```
$this->db->get("table1");

$comm_numbers = $this->db->count_all_results("table1");

$config['base_url'] = base_url();
$config['total_rows'] = $comm_numbers;
$config['per_page'] = '5';
$config['uri_segment'] = 1;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(1)) ? $this->uri->segment(1) : 0;

$this->load->model("model_get_all");
$data["results"] = $this->model_get_all->getData1($config['per_page'], $page);
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: Yes, that finally works! Thanks Erman, and Koala_Dev too. Great method.

Comment: But is there any way we can save $num and $offset for pagination?

Comment: Yes. I will update now the answer and I will add `$num` and `$offset`

Comment: Thanks for such fast update but i got Error Number: 1327 Undeclared variable: $offset. I'm using default CI pagination method

Comment: try with " " (double ') @AlexanderYakovluk

Comment: @AlexanderYakovluk I update the answer. Copy paste and try please!

Comment: @AlexanderYakovluk Be sure that `$num` and `$offset` are declared before!. Print before query, to see they are declare, because the Query works!

Comment: Look, Edit the Question, and put the controller function, and I will check, because the problem is at uri segment. At the first time, $offset is `null`.

Comment: @AlexanderYakovluk Did pagination works before in this form that you done?

Comment: @AlexanderYakovluk, ok. Check again. Tell me if is everything ok.

Comment: Almost perfect. Now list of articles got limited and pagination links appear. But if i press page link i get 404. I work now on my main page. And pagination link look like 'base_url/:num' (just example). Before my paginations were on base_url()/news/:num(example). Thank you again that you did such a huge job helping me and hopefully whole newbie community in future :)

Comment: You just change the `base_url` and also don't forget to change number of uri_segment (at all places on controller) because in this form you get the number of offset when you change the page. You are welcome. You can follow me on twitter or whatever and ask me for everything.